# What is the input for `f` function? in Optional exercise?

Tags: scala

taken from this [excercise](https://github.com/dcsobral/Optional/blob/master/Optional.scala)

```
  def map[B](f: A => B): Optional[B] =
    fold(f andThen some, none[B]) // what is the input for `f` function. Run `f` on what?

  def some[A](a: A): Optional[A] = new Optional[A] {
    def fold[X](some: A => X, none: => X) = some(a)
  }
```

What is `f` running on? what is its input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f is going to run on an Option you supply.

```
val x = Some("test")
val y = x.map(_.toUpperCase) //y is still Option[String] value is Some(TEST)
```

y will be transformed by that function and remain an Option (y is Option[String]).
If you think of Option as a collection of one item only it may seem more natural to call map or fold on it.

Two good links:

In first article find section: Options can be viewed as collections

http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html

This second article is focused on the question of fold vs map on option.

http://kwangyulseo.com/2014/05/21/scala-option-fold-vs-option-mapgetorelse/